# Mathematic books

Tags: reference-request, discrete-mathematics, summation

Can anyone recommend good books in which I can find information about interesting sums (like Harmonic number, sum of polynomials etc). The only book in which I found any information was Concrete Mathematics by Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

- [$A=B$](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), by Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger (freely available)
- *Combinatorial Identities*, by Riordan (a classic)
- [*generatingfunctionology*](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), by Wilf (freely available)

Comment: thanks for the A = B book, which I had never heard of.